# I cannot connect to database when I set the root password to "no password"

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have a problem with phpmyadmin.I changed the empty password of the root user in phpmyadmin to *No password* and when i tried to open phpmyadmin I received the following error:

> 1045 - **Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server. Retry
>   to connect

Is it possible to fix phpmyadmin, without reinstalling it? I am using Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your phpMyAdmin configuration. On Mac it should be under `/Sites/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

Change **`AllowNoPassword`** to **`TRUE`**:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

https://www.simplified.guide/phpmyadmin/enable-login-without-password

**EDIT:**

As [PHPMyAdmin docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) say:

> **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']**:
>
> When using **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] set to ‘config’**, this is
>   the user/password-pair which phpMyAdmin will use to connect to the
>   MySQL server. This user/password pair is not needed when HTTP or
>   cookie authentication is used and should be empty.

so `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` is used only, when you set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']`. It has nothing to do with AllowNoPassword :)

Comment: This line of code doesn't exist in MAMP's config.inc.php file, but I fixed it by adding $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE; and changing the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root'; to emtpy string. Now it works. Thanks for the hlep, but can you explain me why the code is not written and the password is root, despite I changed to  "No password"?

Comment: @KaloianMateev - I updated my answer, so you can read about `password` option. I don't know why there wasn't `AllowNoPassword` in your actual config - maybe it's default setting on Mac? I'm glad that it works now, though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the actual root password to the string "No password" then the login should work normally but if you haven't set a password then try just logging in using that blank input and that tells phpmyadmin you dont want to try and use a password for the login.

Comment: I changed the root password to the string "No password". I am not sure what you mean by using blank input. I cannot enter phpmyadmin at all.

Comment: So you go to 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin and neither of them show anything?